# Rendering high poly to low poly normals. UV are out of bounds

Tags: uv, workflow, normals, normal-map

I have a high poly mesh that I'm trying to render the normals to a low poly mesh material. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. When I bake the high poly normals to low poly the UVs are not right. I guess the easiest way to explain is with some screen shots. [image]

For this simple test I duplicated the low poly, added the sub div modifier, added additional edge loops to sharpen edges etc. Here's the high res model.

Here's the low res model
[image]

Here's the high res model
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is due to the *Margin* setting found in the *Bake* panel. Basically it causes the color to extend a set distance past the UV island boundaries. So your actual bake should have turned out fine. I think the purpose of the *Margin* setting is to ensure that the UV islands never extend past the baked texture.

Comment: The reason for margins is for mip-mapping, a technique used to reduce sampling artifacts that means that the values used for any particular texel are actually a box of values, a box whose boundary can extend outside the official UV.  Here, there is a potential for issues for Byron because the margin doesn't wrap around (assuming the normal map would be called on wrap mode anyways).  But it would be easy to fix by adjusting the UV map.  These pieces could be rotated so that they did not meet the 0/1 Uv edges.